# Solr ignores tokens from third position in a phrase query

Tags: solr

In Solr (4.10.3) I have a query (not using dismax or edismax)

```
t:"past surgical cardiovascular system"
```

the query debug outputs

```
"rawquerystring": "t:\"past surgical cardiovascular system\"",
"querystring": "t:\"past surgical cardiovascular system\"",
"parsedquery": "MultiPhraseQuery(t:\"(ex former formerly previous prior past) (surgery surg surgical operative)\")",
"parsedquery_toString": "t:\"(ex former formerly previous prior past) (surgery surg surgical operative)\"",
```

It seems that solr ignores completelly the tokens from third position onwards.
I'm schoked a little because is the first time I'm noticing this after 8 hours investigation.
What am I missing?
How do I force solr to take the third and fourth token into consideration?

In case it helps, t field is of type:

```
    <fieldType name="text_en_splitting" class="solr.TextField"
        positionIncrementGap="100" autoGeneratePhraseQueries="false">
        <analyzer type="index">
            <!-- <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory" /> -->
            <tokenizer class="solr.PatternTokenizerFactory" pattern="\s*[\{\}\[\]\|\(\):;,]\s*|\b[-/+]\b|\s+[&amp;+-]\s+|(?:\b')?\s+|\.(?=\z|\s)" />
            <!-- in this example, we will only use synonyms at query time <filter
                class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="index_synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true"
                expand="false"/> -->
            <!-- Case insensitive stop word removal. add enablePositionIncrements=true
                in both the index and query analyzers to leave a 'gap' for more accurate
                phrase queries. -->
            <filter class="solr.LimitTokenCountFilterFactory" maxTokenCount="10"/>
            <filter class="solr.ClassicFilterFactory" />
            <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true" />
            <!-- <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory"
                generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1"
                catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1" /> -->
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
            <filter class="solr.EnglishPossessiveFilterFactory" />
            <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt" />
            <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.EnglishMinimalStemFilterFactory" />
        </analyzer>
        <analyzer type="query">
            <!-- <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory" /> -->
            <tokenizer class="solr.PatternTokenizerFactory" pattern="\s*[\{\}\[\]\|\(\):;,]\s*|\b[-/+]\b|\s+[&amp;+-]\s+|(?:\b')?\s+|\.(?=\z|\s)" />
            <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true" />
            <filter class="solr.LimitTokenCountFilterFactory" maxTokenCount="10"/>
            <filter class="solr.ClassicFilterFactory" />
            <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true" />
            <!-- <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory"
                generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="0"
                catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1" /> -->
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
            <filter class="solr.EnglishPossessiveFilterFactory" />
            <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt" />
            <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.EnglishMinimalStemFilterFactory" />
            <!-- <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory" /> -->
        </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
```

I think there is a bug somewhere in solr.

I ran a different query and I got all the tokens in the parsed query:

```
"rawquerystring": "t:\"acute myocardial infarction surgical\"",
"querystring": "t:\"acute myocardial infarction surgical\"",
"parsedquery": "MultiPhraseQuery(t:\"(acute aqt) (myocardial myocrd) (infarct infarction nfrct) (surgery surg surgical)\")",
"parsedquery_toString": "t:\"(acute aqt) (myocardial myocrd) (infarct infarction nfrct) (surgery surg surgical)\"",
```

If I prepend 'past' to the query then the tokes are dropped

```
"rawquerystring": "t:\"past acute myocardial infarction surgical\"",
"querystring": "t:\"past acute myocardial infarction surgical\"",
"parsedquery": "MultiPhraseQuery(t:\"(ex former formerly previous prior past) (acute aqt) (myocardial myocrd)\")",
"parsedquery_toString": "t:\"(ex former formerly previous prior past) (acute aqt) (myocardial myocrd)\"",
```

The analyze page did not give me much details as it analyzes the tokens independently

Comment: What's your synonym file looks like? Especially for these specific tokens. Because it looks like you have one and you are applying it at query time. That might be causing some issues that's worth clarifying.

Comment: the field parsedquery gives you exactly what was expanded from synonyms.txt file: what's in round paranthesis are all the synonyms from that file for a particular token. 'cardiovascular' and 'system' are not listed as whithin any group of those synonyms. so this is not the problem

Answer (score 1):

I finally spotted the problem: I'm using `solr.LimitTokenCountFilterFactory` to limit the query to 10 tokens AFTER using the synonym expansion.
The solution is to remove this filter

Answer (score 0):

You have an extremely complex Query analyzer chain. Fortunately, you can see exactly what happens in it by using *Analyze* screen in the Web Admin UI.

So, you can put your phrase in there (on the right for query processing) and see what happens to the words step by step.

This should tell you if, for example, some terms get swallowed by accident in one of the layers.

Comment: I edited the question by adding more examples: it seems that the tokens are not dropped all the times: I really think there is a problem in Solr query parser

Comment: If there is a bug, it would most likely be around expansion of synonyms. But most likely you will figure out your analyzer chain is not quite right. But try to figure out what is the *minimum* analyzer chain showing your problem and discuss it at the mailing list.